# Parse, Swift and Spotify

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, spotify

This is my first time developing an IOS app, so I'm doing some preliminary research on things I should use.

The app uses Spotify to login and decided to go with Parse for datastorage. My question is how should I handle users? Parse seems to have a PFUser. Is it usable for use with Spotify? From the first glance it seems to need username and password, is there any workaround to it. Or should I store users just as Objects?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you that you should save the login informations and create a `PFUser` in your parse database with the username and password of it. After that you can use the `PFUser` object in your app. Use the `registerInBackground` method to achieve that.

Comment: But spotify takes care of logging in. The only thing I have is the spotify ID? no username or password. Isn't it easier to just have an object for a user?

Comment: Can't you save the user and password if it's done successful? Or is there a custom login-form where you don't have access to the fields?